# Who were these people during the US President's press conference on infrastructure the other day?

Tags: united-states, infrastructure

[image: Here is an image I snapped of them at the press conference]

Here is an image of them I took at the press conference on Tuesday

Answer (score 5):

From left to right:

1. [Steve Mnuchin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Mnuchin), Secretary of the Treasury
2. Donald Trump, President of the United States
3. [Elaine Chao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elaine_Chao), Secretary of Transportation (also the wife of Mitch McConnell)